# How does angular determine whether jQuery is present?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Because I'm getting the weird situation that angular objects like `element` in the link function of a controller ends up being a jQLite object although jQuery is definitely present as in being loaded in memory and successfully used elsewhere on the same page.

The Angular FAQ is rather vague on that question:

> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

So what exactly does 'present' mean?

Comment: I think that jQuery need to be loaded before Angular.

Comment: Probably as simple as checking that window.jQuery is in scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular.js will use jQuery if it's included first, otherwise it will use it's own jqLite. If you load jQuery after AngularJS, AngularJS attaches itself to jqLite but you can still access jQuery through $.

See below the code used by angular.js to determine if jquery is loaded:

```
  // bind to jQuery if present;
  jQuery = window.jQuery;
  // Use jQuery if it exists with proper functionality, otherwise default to us.
  // Angular 1.2+ requires jQuery 1.7+ for on()/off() support.
  // Angular 1.3+ technically requires at least jQuery 2.1+ but it may work with older
  // versions. It will not work for sure with jQuery <1.7, though.
  if (jQuery && jQuery.fn.on) {
    jqLite = jQuery;
    extend(jQuery.fn, {
      scope: JQLitePrototype.scope,
      isolateScope: JQLitePrototype.isolateScope,
      controller: JQLitePrototype.controller,
      injector: JQLitePrototype.injector,
      inheritedData: JQLitePrototype.inheritedData
    });
```

Changing the order of script tags may not happen very often, but it could occur if you start modularising the codebase. In particular, [this issue has happened](http://branchandbound.net/blog/web/2013/08/some-angularjs-pitfalls/) while using some module loaders like RequireJS.